# How can I detect whether my python class instance is cast as an integer or float?

Tags: python, class, types, casting

I have a python class to calculate the number of bits when they have been specified using "Kb", "Mb" or "Gb" notation.  I assigned a `@property` to the `bits()` method so it will always return a `float` (thus working well with `int(BW('foo').bits)`).

However, I am having trouble figuring out what to do when a pure class instance is cast as an `int()`, such as `int(BW('foo'))`.  I have already defined `__repr__()` to return a string, but it seems that that code is not touched when the class instance is cast to a type.

Is there any way to detect within my class that it is being cast as another type (and thus permit me to handle this case)?

```
>>> from Models.Network.Bandwidth import BW
>>> BW('98244.2Kb').bits
98244200.0
>>> int(BW('98244.2Kb').bits)
98244200
>>> BW('98244.2Kb')
98244200.0
>>> type(BW('98244.2Kb'))
<class 'Models.Network.Bandwidth.BW'>
>>>
>>> int(BW('98244.2Kb'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'BW'
>>>
```

Comment: Have you read about `__int__()` and `__float__()` special method names yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

[__int__()](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__)

[__float__()](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__float__)

Comment: [no](http://www.google.com/search?q=__float__+python&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) (click the link for google search)

Comment: @Mike Pennington: http://docs.python.org shouldn't present too many difficulties.  It's always the correct link for Python documentation.  I'm surprised you didn't find it and use the search available there.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you want lies within overriding `__trunc__` and `__float__` in the Models.Network.Bandwidth.BW class:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class NumBucket:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = float(value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def bits(self):
        return float(self.value)

    def __trunc__(self):
        return int(self.value)

a = NumBucket(1092)
print a
print int(a)
print int(a.bits())
```

Comment: If you convert a float to an int, you 'truncate' part of the value

Comment: Guido disagrees. http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-January/076640.html